# Referencing an Object Inside an Object

Tags: java, class

I am creating a game in Java and need to create a list of all of the rooms in it.

I have a 'Rooms' class that has the code for the room, i.e. room name, items in the room etc.

In the Room class I want to have a static ArrayList that has all of the room objects in the whole game in there. This is needed for a method I am working on.

I have created an ArrayList field:

```
private static ArrayList<Rooms> listOfRooms = new ArrayList<Rooms>();
```

In the initialisation of each instance of Rooms, I wish to add that instance to the listOfRooms ArrayList.

I assume you start with `listOfRooms.add()`, but what would you actually put in the parameter to add the current object to the list of Rooms objects?

Comment: You need to get the static list and then add to it.

Comment: You'd better not use any collection as a static field, collections are mutable i.e. collie class able to modify internal state. If you really need a collection (I suppose you don't), try a [singleton pattern](https://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples). Enum singleton (Singleton of Bloch) choose is better. BTW, I suppose you've just need an enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd add `this` to the list; `this` being a reference to the current object (`a Room` in this case) being worked on:

```
listOfRooms.add(this);
```

Note though, having `listOfRooms` as a static member of the class is a bad idea. With this setup, you can only ever have one list, and anyone can alter the list however they want since it's public.

It would likely be much better to create something like a `Hotel` class and make it a member of that:

```
class Hotel {
    ArrayList<Rooms> listOfRooms = new ArrayList<Rooms>();
}
```

Now you can at least have multiple hotels if necessary with separate lists of rooms, and to modify the rooms, code would at least require a reference to the hotel.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Carcigenicate said, it's always better to have more abstraction in object oriented programming.
For example, Hotel object has a Floor ArrayList in it. Each Floor object contains ArrayList of Room and so on.